# Powerpoint access to online fonts e.g Google fonts API

Tags: api, fonts, powerpoint

is there a way Powerpoint presentation can access online fonts so as to not lose formatting when sharing a powerpoint presentation. I'm working with Powerpoint Mac 2008 which does not have an embed fonts option in the 'Save As' dialogue box. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if this is at all possible and license-wise ok this would need to be solved with an Add-In which in turn interacts with the Google fonts API... or just share the presentation as PDF with fonts embedded...

Comment: To add a bit more:  Mac PPT 2008 doesn't support add-ins.  Earlier and later versions of PowerPoint do.  And with a few exceptions, neither Windows nor Mac apps manage fonts; they depend on the operating system to supply available fonts.

Comment: Many thanks for you thoughts / clarification. PDF's are my preferred format but clients inevitably need to make amends to their content. I was hopping for some ind of 'access fonts any where solution'.

Comment: You may want to ask this at superuser.com instead.